# Could an prettier plugin enable the ability to set newline count after imports?

Tags: eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

We're using this eslint rule.

`import/newline-after-import": ["error", { "count": 2 }]`

It puts 2 newlines after imports, but, when using prettier it immediately overrides and sets the newline spacing to 1.

Is this something that could be made configurable with a prettier plugin?